# Cannot change search_path persistently

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, parameters

I have a problem with PostgreSQL: when I use C# to connect to PostgreSQL, I always need to use `SchemaName.Table`. So I wonder how to fix it.

I found that they say use:

```
set search_path to SchemaName;  <---  It can work
```

Then, the first time I look my `search_path` with:

```
show search_path
```

I get:

```
 search_path
--------------
 mySchemaName
```

But in my C# code, I still need to add the schema name, so I look again, and I get:

```
 search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
```

Comment: I am not following. The title of your question says pgAdmin yet the question itself is talking  about C#. What are you actually using? Also where are you setting the `search_path`? Please add answers as update to your question. Per information here [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) SET will only last for the current session. If you want it to stick between session then you need to change [postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html).

Comment: sorry about that. I think that set search_path didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, you are wondering why changing `search_path` with `SET` isn't persistent.

`SET` only changes a parameter for the current database session. If you want to change `search_path` for a certain database in a persistent fashion, use

```
ALTER DATABASE mydbname SET search_path = myschemaname;
```

The new setting will not become effective for current sessions, only sessions established after you run the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ALTER SYSTEM SET` below then restart PostgreSQL to set a parameter persistently. *The parameter with `ALTER SYSTEM SET` is set to `postgresql.auto.conf` rather than `postgresql.conf`:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET search_path TO <Schema-Name>;
```